# Is it possible to define autocracy and subsequently legislate against it?

Tags: united-states, president

Many have accused POTUS of being autocratic.  (Both Donald Trump and Barack Obama).  Is it possible to define the criteria for autocracy and enact a way of preventing this?

Comment: That's kind of what a constitution is for, without defining what autocratic means.

Comment: It is possible for a president to *exhibit autocratic tendencies*, even without the constitutional means to fully implement those impulses.

Answer (score 2):

Defining autocracy is the easy part, with [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autocracy) defining it as "government in which one person possesses unlimited power".

The actual line is of course much fuzzier. Even in countries where there is a single person designated as the head of state and government, such as [Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Saudi_Arabia) and several other arab countries where a Sheik or Sultan is the penultimate ruler, the military in the country and in some cases the religious elite have enough clout to influence the decisions of the ruler lest he/she incur their wrath. The only current true autocracy that comes to mind is the DPRK, and they are secretive enough about their workings that it is nearly impossible to know if anyone outside of their leader actually has influence.

In the United States, autocracy is prevented by the [balance of powers](https://www.usconstitution.net/consttop_sepp.html) outlined in the constitution. Obama was politically knowledgeable and thus - towards the end of his term when he went on the executive order spree that drew condemnation from his political opponents - was generally able to toe the line on the balance of powers, though some of his executive orders [were shut down](http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/03/politics/supreme-court-rejects-obama-administration-request-on-immigration-orders/index.html). Trump by comparison with a lack of political savvy has brought the balance of powers to the forefront, especially earlier in his term with the [first attempts at the travel ban](http://www.foxnews.com/us/2017/01/29/us-judge-bars-deportations-under-trump-travel-ban.html).

Long story short, the US does not need to legislate against autocracy. It has already been eliminated as a possibility by the constitution and cannot be changed without constitutional amendment.

[image]

Democracy and the balance of powers in action